Why would unrelated breakers start tripping after installing whole home surge protector?
I have an (100+ years) old house in the USA. Two days ago we got a whole home surge protector connected to two adjacent 20 amp breakers (and to ground/neutral) in the main panel as per the instructions. No other changes were made in this panel (unless inadvertently when routing the surge protector's wires).
Yesterday evening I came home and a 15 amp breaker had tripped. It had never tripped before, and no new loads have been added to the circuit. A different 15 amp breaker (one on a tandem breaker in the same row, on the other side) tripped within the next 15 minutes. (No additional trips since then). Any ideas what could cause this, or what I should do?
Other info that could be relevant: We know this house has had some poor electrical work done before we purchased it. E.g. when we moved in the red wires for our wired smoke alarms just use for communication were incorrectly connected to a breaker in the main panel. I have seen some LED light bulbs on one of the that circuits that tripped flicker occasionally over the past few years (the bulbs themselves didn't seem to be dying). Lights on a few other circuits sometimes flicker as well. The main panel and directly attached wiring appear much newer than the home (QO load center and standard NM cable).

When you say "tripped", was it due to over-current or to ground fault protection?

@DrMoishePippik over-current. They are not GFCI or AFCI breakers.

Disconnect the surge protector. Do breakers still blow?

Look for wires touching the box or each other. And, as @keshlam states, disconnect the surge protector for a while.

It seems that you may be heading up voltages, that means that one phase is feeding your circuit on your hot conductor and the other phase is feeding in voltage from the neutral. This is generally caused by losing a phase.
First, I would check my connection from the surge arrestor to the panel and make sure that the conductors are connected correctly. Especially make sure the neutrals are connected properly.
If that isn't it I would disconnect the surge arrestor and see if problem tripping stops. If it does, you probably have a bad surge arrestor and it needs to be replaced under warranty.
Other than that you will probably need some more professional help that can work with you on site.
Warning: This is not a good situation. If what I am thinking is true, it means that any appliances or equipment that are connected to those breakers that are tripping, could be getting 240 volts instead of 120. It will burn them up and possibly cause a fire.
Obviously this needs immediate attention. Stay safe.

I think you meant to write "caused by losing a neutral". That's what makes the neutral float away from zero volts and potentially close to a full phase voltage. Losing a phase is safe,just makes some circuits not get any power at all while other circuits work normally.
